# Show only sites in quick launch and top navigation menu

Tags: navigation, quick-launch, top-link-bar

Is it possible to show only sites and subsites on the quick launch (left navigation and top navigation menu). By default all the lists and libraries are also being displayed on menus.

Note: I am asking the deployable way of this, not from the UI way (configuring manually on the settings pages.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this link 
http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=285
then click Navigation Under Look and Feel Hide List And Library link.

Comment: I could not see any "Hide List and Library" option on the current navigation settings page.

Comment: so you remove links Library and list Section

Comment: i think you don't understand me properly.